# Can't resolve a promise with an ElementArrayFinder as argument

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm writing a function in protractor that gets all the row elements of a list. The function checks for multiple types of lists. It uses the method `isPresent()` to check if one type of list exists. If not, it moves on to the next type. Since the `isPresent()` method is async, I must return my array of rows through a Promise. I am trying to return it as an `ElementArrayFinder.`

```
  public getAllListElements(listName: string): Promise<ElementArrayFinder> {

    return new Promise<ElementArrayFinder>((resolve) => {
      element(by.css('.list-title')).isPresent().then((result) => {
        let elems: ElementArrayFinder;
        if (result === true) {
          elems = element(by.cssContainingText('.list-title', listName)).element(by.xpath('../..')).all(by.css('mat-row'));
          resolve(elems);
        } else {
          elems = element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-header-cell', listName)).element(by.xpath('../..')).all(by.css('mat-row'));
          resolve(elems);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

After debugging, I can confirm that the data stored in the `elems` variable is an ElementArrayFinder. Therefore, the function which has called the `getAllListElements` function recieves an Array OF `ElementFinders` in it's callback. Here is one of the calls:

```
  navigateAllContacts() {
    this.helpers.getAllListElements('Contacts').then((contacts) => {
      contacts.count().then((size) => {
        console.log('Navigating trough ' + size + ' contacts');
      });
    });
  }
```

So since i'm expecting `contacts` to be an `ElementArrayFinder`, i try calling its `count()` method. This fails since `contacts` is of the wrong type.

I have found a workaround to this. I "encapsulate" my `ElementArrayFinder` in a parent object and I resolve my promise with it. This way, the data type doesn't change. But I have to access the object's member in my callback, which is not ideal.

Here is the workaround:

```
  public getAllListElements(listName: string): Promise<any> {

    return new Promise<any>((resolve) => {
      element(by.css('.list-title')).isPresent().then((result) => {
        let elems = { eaf : null};
        if (result === true) {
          elems.eaf = element(by.cssContainingText('.list-title', listName)).element(by.xpath('../..')).all(by.css('mat-row'));
          resolve(elems);
        } else {
          elems.eaf = element(by.cssContainingText('.mat-header-cell', listName)).element(by.xpath('../..')).all(by.css('mat-row'));
          resolve(elems);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

And the method call:

```
  navigateAllContacts() {
    this.helpers.getAllListElements('Contacts').then((contacts) => {
      contacts.eaf.count().then((size) => {
        console.log('Navigating trough ' + size + ' contacts');
      });
    });
  }
```

Any ideas of why this data alteration may occur?

Comment: Does it work if you try `.then((contacts: ElementArrayFinder) => { // do stuff })` in `navigateAllContacts()`?

Comment: I've tried typing the callback argument but sadly it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code.

```
navigateAllContacts() {
    this.helpers.getAllListElements('Contacts').then(function(contacts) => {
      contacts.count().then(function(size) => {
        console.log('Navigating trough ' + size + ' contacts');
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck!